# How to count string occurrences in an array of strings in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

I need to iterate over an array of strings, count the occurrences of each string, and return a object with the value and the number of occurrences.

I'm trying to use the array reduce function to achieve such thing, but, despite the attempts, I haven't been able to achieve that yet.

So I have the following:

```
["tony", "tony", "tony", "tony", "kassandra", "tony", "tony", "kassandra"]
```

I need the output:

```
[{ name: "tony", matches: 6 }, { name: "kassandra", matches: 2 }]
```

What should I use to obtain the above output?

I have tried the following:

```
const names = nameList.map((user) => user.name);

const reduce = names.reduce((p, c) => {
  if (p == c) {
    return { name: p, matches: `idk what put here yet` };
  }
  return c;
});
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Array.reduce is a good start.  Let’s see your array.reduce code.

Comment: Added a typescript version

Comment: @tevemadar here a Typescript solution is asked, so it's different, not a duplicate. Plus specific solution with `Array::reduce()` was asked. Plus a different desired output format. Plus a lot of effort was invested by responders. So flagging it as a duplicate is a shallow reaction

Comment: you should add `typescript` tag to typescript related questions

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev (1) The OP is not _specifically_ asking for TypeScript: types are not directly involved, so this is actually a valid JavaScript question as well. (2) Solutions were/are not required to use `Array::reduce()`; the OP simply stated that they had _tried_ that approach. Please do not read extra meaning into statements such as that.

Comment: (3) I don't think "effort invested" is applicable. If it's a duplicate, it's a duplicate. If it were a definite duplicate, it wouldn't matter _how_ many people wrote answers if it's been well-answered before. As an aside, in certain cases, depending on the relative states of the questions, the _older_ one could be marked as a duplicate of the _newer_ one.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, count the occurrences of each name in the array.
Secondly, convert it into an object with the desired format of `name` and their `matches`.

```js
const names = ["tony", "tony", "tony", "tony", "kassandra", "tony", "tony", "kassandra"];
const counts = {};
//1.
names.forEach(name => {
  if (counts[name]) {
    counts[name] += 1;
  } else {
    counts[name] = 1;
  }
});
//2.
const result = Object.keys(counts).map(name => {
  return {
    name: name,
    matches: counts[name]
  };
});
console.log(result);
```

If you want to use `.reduce()` approach to counting occurrences of names:

```
const counts = names.reduce((acc, name) => {
    acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

Another approach to convert occurrences back into an object using `Object.entries()`

```
Object.entries(counts).map(([name, matches]) => ({ name, matches }));
```

Two approaches combined:

```js
const names = ["tony", "tony", "tony", "tony", "kassandra", "tony", "tony", "kassandra"];
const counts = names.reduce((acc, name) => {
    acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
const result = Object.entries(counts).map(([name, matches]) => ({ name, matches }));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Downvoted because a) No reduce was used as asked. b) You could do this in one loop.

Comment: I've updated the answer with `.reduce()`, I used forEach just for simplicity?

Comment: Already changed my downvote :) Just wanted to note that I much aprove the simplicity but not without the best approach. Now it has both! Perfect! ;)

Comment: That could be done with 1 line, no need in 2 steps here, check my solution

Comment: Instead of the fancy `acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + 1;`, you could do it in two lines to make it more readable: `if (!acc[name]) acc[name] = 0; acc[name] += 1;`.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes rollbacked your edit by mistake, recovered manually, sorry

Comment: @XMehdi01 interestingly enough, but the OP requested a Typescript version. oops, so I had to add it too

Answer (score 1):

A pure `Array::reduce()` Typescript solution.

We provide an aggregate object (`r` in the callback) where we store 2 values: the result array `arr` with the desired output and a map `map` where we can easily find an existing array items to increment found matches:

[A live typescript gist is here.](https://playcode.io/1519818)

```
const names = ["tony", "tony", "tony", "tony", "kassandra", "tony", "tony", "kassandra"];

interface MatchItem {
  name: string, 
  matches: number
};

const result = names.reduce((r, name) => {
  const {arr, map} = r;
  const item = map.get(name);
  item ? item.matches++ : map.set(name, arr[arr.length] = { name, matches: 1 });
  return r;
}, { arr: [], map: new Map } as {arr: MatchItem[], map: Map<string, MatchItem>}).arr;

console.log(result);
```

JS version:

```js
const names = ["tony", "tony", "tony", "tony", "kassandra", "tony", "tony", "kassandra"];

const result = names.reduce((r, name) => {
  const {arr, map} = r;
  const item = map.get(name);
  item ? item.matches++ : map.set(name, arr[arr.length] = { name, matches: 1 });
  return r;
}, { arr: [], map: new Map }).arr;

console.log(result);
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1">

// randomly fill with names
const src = 'tony kassandra alex peter mike arnold tina maria stephen nicolas samuel sonya natali elena julia'.split(' ');

let i = 16000000;
const names = [];
while (i--) {
    names.push(src[Math.floor(Math.random() * src.length)]);
}

// @benchmark XMehdi01's solution
const counts = names.reduce((acc, name) => {
    acc[name] = (acc[name] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
}, {});
Object.entries(counts).map(([name, matches]) => ({ name, matches }));

//@benchmark Alexander's solution
names.reduce((r, name) => {
    const {arr, map} = r;
    const item = map.get(name);
    item ? item.matches++ : map.set(name, arr[arr.length] = { name, matches: 1 });
    return r;
}, { arr: [], map: new Map }).arr;

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good one, but even though I prefer *readable code* over *short code*

Comment: I have to admit @XMehdi01 is correct on readability. However I feel like this could be more readable. A solution would be to split up the code as 1) a one liner 2) the one liner split up on multiple lines with clear comments on each line.

Comment: Off topic: I feel like you improved a lot this last month, but aside from your good solutions, always try to explain as much as possible! You can always directly submit your solution and edit a more detailed answer later :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir thank you for the feedback. btw i wrongly read the desired output in the question so provided a wrong result. the desired result required a more intricated logic, but i was able to manage it with 1 Array::reduce() call

Comment: @Wimanicesir added a description. looks ok?

Comment: @XMehdi01 thanks for input, actually i produced a wrong output. otherwise the code looked ok imho. fixed and benchmarked our solution. besides readability we should take into account performance also imho

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I agree with you!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired output, you can use the reduce function along with an object to store the counts of each name. Here's an example of how you can implement it:

```js
const nameList = ["tony", "tony", "tony", "tony", "kassandra", "tony", "tony", "kassandra"];

const countMatches = nameList.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc[curr]) {
    acc[curr]++;
  } else {
    acc[curr] = 1;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.entries(countMatches).map(([name, matches]) => ({ name, matches }));

console.log(result);
```

Output:

```json
[
  { name: 'tony', matches: 6 },
  { name: 'kassandra', matches: 2 }
]
```

In the code above, the `reduce` function is used to iterate over the `nameList` array. The accumulator (`acc`) is an object that keeps track of the count for each name. If the current name (`curr`) already exists as a property in the accumulator, the count is incremented by 1. Otherwise, a new property is created with the name as the key and an initial count of 1.

After the `reduce` operation, we use `Object.entries` to convert the object back into an array of key-value pairs. Then, we use `map` to transform each key-value pair into an object with `name` and `matches` properties. Finally, the result is stored in the `result` variable.

Note: In your attempted code, you were comparing `p` and `c` using the equality operator (`==`) which would only compare the values, not the count of occurrences. Additionally, you didn't handle the case where the name is not equal to the previous one.

Comment: The implementation is pretty much the same as @XMehdi01's, but I give you an upvote for the explanation.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Then you should be thanking ChatGPT instead, not the user who didn't write it.

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be; the final note doesn't _seem_ like ChatGPT (especially what I would consider a missing comma after "the equality operator (`==`)".), but could have been added by the user themselves onto the end of whatever ChatGPT generated. However, the opening doesn't restate the problem as is typical. I would also like to note that the two explanation paragraphs are pretty much how I would write it myself, so we can't go by those two much, at least in isolation. My overall opinion is that it isn't, or at least is only partially.